# How to pass dynamic parameter and inject repository in ActionFilter in asp.net Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

The below web api created in asp.net Core 2.2. I have implemented the ActionFilter in it. I want to inject the repository in my action filter for fetching out the details.

1. API

```
// Action Filter
[CheckPermissionFilter("authorization.modules.add")] 
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Module module)
{
    // API Code
}
```

2. Action filter class

```
public class CheckPermissionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
   private readonly string _permission;
   PermissionRepository repository;

   public CheckPermissionFilter(string permission)
   {
       _permission = permission;
   }

   public async override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
   {
       string userID = "12345678990";

       if (!await repository.check("","",_permission))
       {
           return;   
       } 
   }
}
```

I want to inject repository to the Action filter.The parameter passed in `[CheckPermissionFilter("authorization.modules.add")]` are dynamic i.e. in another api it could be `[CheckPermissionFilter("authorization.modules.update")]` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
var repo = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IRepository>();
```

in OnActionExecuting() method